# Do people with missing/amputated limbs have the same EMG readings as normal people?

Tags: muscle, nerves

I'm doing a research on EMG and it's readings for my engineering project, and as I am not a doctor nor a medical student I have no way of finding such a thing out by myself.
All the research that I could find on this subject was conducted on people with healthy limbs, therefore most I could gather is to "where to stick the electrode to get the wave".
I tried looking for medical forums and this is the best site I found. any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Cat-Bot, welcome to Medical Sciences. I think if you watch [this video](https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/health/treatment-tests-and-therapies/electromyography-emg), it will become clear that you can't record an EMG from an amputated limb because the receiving electrode goes *on the target muscle*.

Comment: Thank you Ian for your reply. I was looking into EMG as I wanted to capture the impulses of the nerves that once led somewhere, to be specific, I wanted to capture those impulses that were left behind after the amputation/loss, and now are considered redundant. however, I believe that body should still have those impulses *stored in the back of the head*, if you will. Is it possible to capture those waves by any way, shape or form?

Comment: I also forgot to add, this question was born from research I saw on [this link](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-18503-8), where pictures of fingers and their EMG readings where shown, with fingers clearly showing no electrodes attached to them. might have been an aesthetic trick, just to clearly display fingers, or its just the PWS doing its thing. I really don't know. again, that's why I am here :D

Comment: I sit corrected. :)

Comment: @IanCampbell These are still EMGs, recorded from existing muscle.

Comment: @BryanKrause Ah, I see, thanks for the clarification. I should have read more carefully.

Comment: @Cat-Bot note that the finger muscles are all up in the fore-arm, not in the hand (look at the lower side of your arm and clench fingers one at a time to see them in action). So to do the recording you would attach the electrodes on the fore-arm, not the hand.

Comment: @IanCampbell I must say that the last link you provided me with helped me very much, Its better than any research I've come across so far. Thank you so much for that

Comment: I've come back after doing some more research into EMG and myoelectric control. I now understand that finger muscles start from forearm, although no research suggests that people with missing fingers should be able to still do the contracting motion.
To put it roughly, I want to know if I ask a person with missing fingers "can you contract [a] finger", will they be able to, to some extent, contract the leftover forearm muscle?

Comment: @Cat-Bot yes they can, assuming there isn't damage to the muscle/tendons or nerves. This is the basis for the control of some prosthetics. [e.g.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7506660/)